# CMD Bash equivalent of * usage in variable declaration

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to use variable expansion in a .bat script.
In Bash I'd do

`MyVar="*.jar"`

when doing

`echo $MyVar`

I got

`file1.jar file2.jar file3.jar`

On CMD doing

```
set MyVar="*.jar"
echo %MyVar%
```

I got `*.jar`

How can I get the same result as in Bash on Cmd?

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths